# Shorter notation for getting an object field

Tags: php, oop, notation

I'm wondering if there's a short notation in PHP for getting an object field when creating an object.

For example, in Java, I don't have to put a newly created object in a variable in order to get one of it's fields.
Example:

```
public class NewClass {
    public int testNum = 5;
}
```

now, to get the `testNum` field in a newly created object all I have to do is:

`int num = (new NewClass()).testNum;`

While a similar case in PHP would force me to do this:

```
$obj = new NewClass();
$num = $obj->testNum;
```

Is there a way in PHP to do it in one statement?
Note: I cannot edit the classes.

Comment: It seems to me that the Java version you showed could be rather wasteful. I'm not a Java expert, but doesn't the code snipped you showed essentially just create an object, access a property of the object and then throws the object away?  My understanding is that object creation is expensive in both java and PHP so creating an object and then throwing it away would be rather wasteful wouldn't it?

Comment: Why assign the value to `$num`? It's already in `$obj->testNum` Can you show more of the code so we can see why you would be willing to spend a considerable amount of time just to get rid of one line?

Comment: There's no specific code, I just find myself sometimes in a situation where only need one var of an object, and it seems more convenient to write only one line instead of two for such a thing.

Comment: RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/instance-method-call

Comment: @nikic, yeah exactly like that. They even added the array [n] options :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for either static properties, or constants

```
public class NewClass {
  const NUM = 5;
  public static $num = 5;
}
$num = NewClass::NUM;
$num = NewClass::$num;
```

If you are really need object members, then no, PHP currently doesn't support this, but its scheduled for the next 5.4 release.

Comment: So, if the variable is not static or constant, and is set at creation time, I can't do it?

Comment: You *could* wrap the code in a function that you can parameterize, but you **shouldn't**.

Comment: You can access it by using a temporary variable (your are already doing it in your example), but not in a single statement. If you plan to read and understand your code later, I suggest using the variable ;) However, if you always need just the value, there is no reason to implement it as an object member, instead of a static property, or a constant

Answer (score 2):

You can create a wrapper create function in your class that calls the constructor, then you can simply:

```
$num = NewClass::Create()->testNum;
```

Comment: @OZ_: Depends on what you are going to achieve ;) This is just an implementation of the factory pattern. However, I don't think its wanted _here_.

Comment: @KingCrunch only if "bad" kind of implementation. Static methods is a bad practice.

Comment: I don't actually want to create anything, or edit the classes for that matter (I don't have access to the code anyways). I just want to get the var with one statement :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only with functions/methods calls.
`new` is not a function, but a language construct.